# Duplicate PHP files in Magento installation?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

A client's Magento site had weird characters in the top of Magento Connect:

[image]

We tried installing a plugin and got the following error:

[image: Magento Install Error]

It turns out the problem was a bunch of (hidden) duplicate PHP files in `lib/Mage/Connect`. For example, there's `Remote.php` but there was also `._Remote.php`. [This forum post](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/266146/) was how we found out the details.

(Deleting the duplicate files corrected the problem).

I'm wondering -- has anyone else experienced this duplicate PHP file problem in Magento before? Any idea what the cause is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These files are mostly likely meta-data files for OS X's HFS+ file system. See [this entire thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14980/why-are-dot-underscore-files-created-and-how-can-i-avoid-them) on the Apple Stack Exchange for some good starting points if you're interested in the details.

Oversimplifying things, when you create a tar archive on OS X these files are included along with the "real" file.  This allows Macintosh specific meta data to survive the trip into a file format that wasn't created specifically for the Mac.  If you untar the files on a Mac, the meta-data is preserved.  If you untar the files on a non-Mac, the `._` files are generated in case the meta data is needed.

My guess is, at some point someone `tar`ed up those files to move them to the production server from their Mac, which brought along the the `._` files for the ride.  You can avoide this in the future by running

```
export COPYFILE_DISABLE=true
```

from the terminal prior to copying the files. Details on [this here](https://superuser.com/questions/61185/why-do-i-get-files-like-foo-in-my-tarball-on-os-x).

(It's pretty bizarre that PHP would attempt to include those files instead of the correct files — did you debug this far enough to know why/what connect through it was doing?)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! No, not sure why it included the duplicate files. Maybe internally Magento just includes all PHP files in certain directories?

Comment: @KyleFox While I'd never rule out anything when it comes to Magento, this is far more likely to be a problem on how the files were transfered/copied to your server at some point.